# 404 Not Found nginx/1.14.2 after upgrade PHP 8 on Azure - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, azure, nginx, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to upgrade from PHP 7.4 to PHP 8 on Azure App Service (Linux).

It shows the following error:
404 Not Found - nginx/1.14.2

I understood that the problem is that Azure from PHP 8 use NGINX instead Apache.
So I followed the steps given here:
https://azureossd.github.io/2021/09/02/php-8-rewrite-rule/index.html

For a while it's worked correctly but from the day after it stopped to work and restart to show the error "404 Not Found
nginx/1.14.2"

This is my default file:

```
server {
    #proxy_cache cache;
    #proxy_cache_valid 200 1s;
    listen 8080;
    listen [::]:8080;
    root /home/site/wwwroot;
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;
    server_name  example.com www.example.com; 

    location / {            
        index  index.php index.html index.htm hostingstart.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /html/;
    }
    
    # Disable .git directory
    #
    location ~ /\.git {
        deny all;
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    # Add locations of phpmyadmin here.
    #
    location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(|/.*)$;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout         300; 
        fastcgi_send_timeout           3600; 
        fastcgi_read_timeout           3600;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
        fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
        fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe it could be relevant: now with the configuration above works the home page (ex. https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/public ) but anything others page doesn't work (ex https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/public/test )

Comment: Did you manage to fix this ? I am facing the same issue on App Service + PHP8.0 + nginx combo. The nginx config is very similar to what you have shared. I am stuck on it from days.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered similar issues with the change from Apache to Nginx in Azure App Services. I did some further research to get my application working and blogged about it at https://www.azurephp.dev/2021/09/php-8-on-azure-app-service/. Maybe the solutions I found can help you further.

Comment: Saved my day. Upgraded PHP version to 8 on an Linux App Service to run WordPress and got 404 on every page except home. Updating nginx configuration was the solution

Answer (score 0):

This is a working nginx configuration with ssl installed. YOu can see this as reference and modify it according to your own

```
    server {
    server_name something.com www.something.com;
    root /var/www/something.com/public;
    
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/something.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/something.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}

server {
    if ($host = www.something.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = something.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    server_name something.com www.something.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

}
```

Comment: Hi Ariful, I tried your setup but couldn't solve.

Answer (score 0):

You could switch the fastcgi_intercept_errors off to get the possible DB connections errors directly in the browser. Then you could get a new diagnostic about the issue.

```
fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
```