# Azure web app laravel api - nginx error 404

Tags: php, laravel, azure, nginx

I'm getting  `404 Not Found nginx/1.14.2` on my azure web app.
I'm using azure web app service connected to the azure MySQL database.

I can't find the problem that causes my API routes to respond as a 404 error.

I checked most of the answers and I don't really get it because I'm new to azure server configuration.
I used ssh to access my files and I don't have an idea how to fix such a problem...

Those are my files like so:
.htaccess in public is :

```
Options -Indexes
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

<Files .env>
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Files>

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

default in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`

````
server {
    #proxy_cache cache;
        #proxy_cache_valid 200 1s;
    listen 8080;
    listen [::]:8080;
    root /home/site/wwwroot/public;
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;
    server_name  example.com www.example.com;

    location / {
        index  index.php index.html index.htm hostingstart.html;
    }
    location /snow/api {
        root /var/www/html/snow/pubic;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /html/;
    }

    # Disable .git directory
    #
    location ~ /\.git {
        deny all;
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    # Add locations of phpmyadmin here.
    #
location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(|/.*)$;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout         300;
        fastcgi_send_timeout           3600;
        fastcgi_read_timeout           3600;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
        fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
        fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
    }
} ```

What am I missing?
````

Comment: I have the same issue on laravel azure web app. Have you found a solution?

Comment: @nelsonym unfortunately no

Comment: This blog might help: https://azureossd.github.io/2022/04/22/PHP-Laravel-deploy-on-App-Service-Linux-copy/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The 404 error basically means that your or your visitor's web browser was able to connect to the website server or host successfully. But, the requested resource, such as a filename or a specific URL, could not be found.
- If you're getting a `404 Not Found Nginx error` and you've double-checked that the asset(s) exists on your server, it's possible that your configuration file is the problem. To verify this, open your `nginx.conf` file and see if your site is utilising the correct root folder path.
- It's possible that it is showing a `404 Not Found Nginx error` because the path is incorrect. Also, double-check your configuration file's rewrite rules to make sure they aren't misconfigured.

Check this similar SO thread workaround -
https://stackoverflow.com/a/70970178

**References -**

1. [PHP 8 on Azure App Service](https://www.azurephp.dev/2021/09/php-8-on-azure-app-service/)
2. [Deploying PHP 8.0 applications with Azure App Service](https://www.schakko.de/2021/09/08/deploying-php-8-0-applications-with-azure-app-service/)

Answer (score 4):

Just in case it helps anyone else with a 404 error using the Linux app service in azure:

Apparently nginx will return a 404 when Laravel has an error. The only evidence of this you will find is by sshing into the instance and looking in the Laravel storage folders logs.

Comment: This was really helpful and works